# RecyclerView isn't show all items without scroll

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, scroll

I have horizontal RecyclerView which has GridView. RecyclerView has 31 elements but 30 elements are visible. I want to show all recyclerView items but all elements aren't visible without scrolling down.

When recyclerView height is 200dp all items are visible, but does not appear while wrap_content. I don't want to give a fixed height because it doesn't look the same on every phone.

**RecyclerView code:**

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
new PagerSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

**Recyclerview layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerView"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Recyclerview item layout:**

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

**GridView item layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Recyclerview all items:**
[image]

**Visible items:**
[image]

**After scrolling:**

[image]

Comment: Which layout manager you're using for your recyclerView?

Comment: LinearLayoutManager. I add my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to adopt some changes in your recycler view in order to achieve this:

1. Recycler view item should be your actual `gridViewLayoutItem`
2. Get rid of your `gridView` (recyclerViewItemLayout for now)
3. Use `GridLayoutManager` as a layout manager for your `recyclerView

```java
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, numberOfColumns));
```

4. You can decide on the `numberOfColumn` based on the screen width by an extension function: higher number of columns for larger screens and vice-versa

Comment: Thank you. My recyclerView has gridViews to all pages. Does it cover all of them

Comment: Your recycler view items should be the direct layout not a grid view. It's bad for performance also not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the RecyclerView is performing nested scrolling even though you have set its height to wrap_content.
You will have to disable nested scrolling too.

```
RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```